# Eloquent migrations vs. manual SQL as not a team

Tags: php, orm, eloquent

**Migration**
I am new to that concept and I think it is useful for teams to keep the database in synch (though I could use a description of the workflow). But I don't get the benefits in working alone.

The downside in having another layer with more probability of failure vs. more comfort in developing seams not like a rational deal to me.

Whether I do in PHP

```
$capsule::schema()->create('properties', function($table) {

    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('name');

});

$capsule::schema()->create('values', function($table) {

    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('value');
    $table->integer('property_id');

});

$capsule::schema()->create('properties_values', function($table)
{
    $table->increments('id');

    $table->integer('property_id'); // the id of the property
    $table->integer('value_id'); // the id of the value that this property depends on

});
```

or in SQL

```
CREATE TABLE `properties` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci

CREATE TABLE `properties_values` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `property_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `value_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci

CREATE TABLE `values` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `value` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `property_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=7 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

seems like a weak difference.

Questions:
A: Are there things to pay attention to, when I decide to manually create tables?
B: *(Already found this point in the docs)* Why are foreign keys not generated automatically and how to do that in migrations?
C: Is there a way to create standard tables from the defined models instead of those schemas?